# One type of integer divisor homology - what does this one measure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, prime-numbers, homology-cohomology, abelian-groups

The set of functions $\{ (d \mid \cdot) : d \in \Bbb{N}\}$ where $$(d\mid x) = \begin{cases} 1, \text{ if } d \mid x, \\ 0, \text{ if } d \nmid x \end{cases}, \ \forall x \in \Bbb{Z}$$

are the "divisor indicator functions" and they generate a subspace of the $\Bbb{Z}$-module $M = \{ f : \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}, f \text{ any function}\}$.  What subspace, I don't know, so we'll just say the one that they generate.  The $(d\mid x)$ are easily seen to be linearly independent (see comment).

Now, consider $\Bbb{Z}$-linear combinations of the $(d\mid \cdot)$'s.

Define $M_n = \{ f \in M : f(x) = \sum_{d \in \Bbb{N}} c_d (d \mid x), \ c_d \in \Bbb{Z} \}, n \geq 0$ where we *do not require all but finitely many $c_d$ to be nonzero* as long as the domain of the functions we consider does not include $0$, since $(d \mid 0) = 1$ always so there would be an infinite sum of coefficients which may not converge.

---

Now, define $\partial = \partial_n : M_n\to M_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 1$ in the obvious way:

Let $d = q_1 \cdots q_n$ be such that $q_1 \leq q_2 \leq \dots \leq q_n$ is the standard ordering of the primes comprising $d$.

$$
\partial (d \mid \cdot) = \partial(q_1 \cdots q_n \mid \cdot) \\ 
= \sum_{i = 1}^n (-1)^i (q_1 \cdots \widehat{q_i} \cdots q_n \mid \cdot)
$$

and extend each $\partial$ in the unique $\Bbb{Z}$-linear way.

Then for example:

$$
\partial(q_1q_2q_3q_4 \mid \cdot) = -(q_2q_3q_4\mid \cdot) + (q_1q_3q_4\mid \cdot) -(q_1q_2q_4\mid \cdot) + (q_1q_2q_3\mid \cdot)
$$

so that:

$$\partial\circ \partial(q_1q_2q_3q_4\mid \cdot) \\
= (q_3q_4 \mid \cdot) - (q_2q_4\mid \cdot) + (q_2q_3 \mid \cdot) \\
- (q_3q_4\mid \cdot) + (q_1q_4\mid \cdot) -(q_1q_3 \mid \cdot) 
+(q_2q_4 \mid \cdot) - \dots \\
= 0
$$

Since we do have a chain complex: $\cdots \xrightarrow{\partial} M_2 \xrightarrow{\partial} M_1 \xrightarrow{\partial} M_0$

**Question.**

> What does the $n$th homology module measure?

---

**Attempt.**

Let $R$ be a ring with $1$ and define $M_n = \{ f : \Bbb{N} \to R \vert f(x) = \sum_{d \in \Bbb{N}, \\ \Omega(d) = n} c_d(d \mid x), c_d \in R \}$.

Then $\partial_n$ defined in the question post is still relevant.  Let $p, q, p_i, q_i$ always mean a prime number, except $p_i$ is the standard $i$th prime number and $q_i$ is the $i$th prime number in some contextual list of prime numbers.  Fix a linear ordering on all prime numbers wherever they occur.  When we write $q_1 \cdots q_n$ we will implicitly mean that $q_1 \leq \dots \leq q_n$ under this chosen ordering.

Define $Z_n = \ker \partial_n$ where $\partial_n : M_n \to M_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 1$.  Similarly define $B_n = \partial_n(M_n)$.

$$
Z_n = \{ f \in M_n : \partial(f)(x)=\sum_{d \in \Bbb{N} \\ \Omega(d) = n} f_d \sum_{q_i \mid d \\ i = 1..\Omega(d)}(-1)^i(\frac{d}{q_i} \mid x) = 0, \ \forall x \in \Bbb{N}\}
$$

where empty summations (no $q \mid d$ exists) are taken to be $0$.

---

$$
B_{n} = \{ \partial(f) = \sum_{d \in \Bbb{N} \\ \Omega(d) = n+1} f_d \sum_{q_i \mid d \\ i = 1..\Omega(d)}(-1)^i(\frac{d}{q_i} \mid x) : f \in M_{n+1}\}
$$

---

A boundary map is $\partial(f)(x) = \sum_{d \in \Bbb{N}} f_d\sum_{q_i \mid d}(-1)^i(\frac{d}{q_i} \mid x)$ so:

$$
B_1 = \partial(M_2) = \sum_{p,q\in \Bbb{P} \\ p\leq q} \Bbb{Z}((q\mid \cdot) - (p\mid \cdot)) \\
B_2 = \partial(M_3) = \sum_{p,q,r\in \Bbb{P} \\ p\leq q \leq r} \Bbb{Z}((qr\mid \cdot) -(pr\mid \cdot) +(pq\mid\cdot)) \\
Z_1 = \ker \partial_1 = \{ f \in M_1 : \sum_{p \in \Bbb{P}} f_p = 0\} \\
Z_2= \ker \partial_2 = \{ f \in M_2 : \sum_{p\leq q} f_{pq}((q\mid \cdot) - (p\mid \cdot)) = 0\}
$$

Comment: You say $(2\mid x) + (3\mid x) = 2(6\mid x)$, but that is not true when $x=2$, for instance.

Comment: I claim these functions are in fact linearly independent: any linear combination $\sum c_d (d \mid x)$ is nonzero when $x$ is the smallest value of $d$ with a nonzero coefficient.

Comment: @BenjaminWright so you're saying they're linearly independent when you take _any_ set of divisors, and they don't have to be from primorial?

Comment: This sounds interesting. In number theory, sums of the form $\sum_{d | n} c_d$ are called divisor sums and are all over the place. That sum is just $\sum_{d \in \mathbb N} c_d (d | n)$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva That's right, you can probably apply this to other arithmetic functions as well.  I always thought there was some way to do homology with prime numbers since $q_1 \cdots q_n$ is like a face in a simplex.  You can't do it purely with terms of the form $q_1 \cdots q_n \in \Bbb{Z}$ because the expressions are then not uniquely determined by their value.  Here the functions however are uniquely determined by linear independence.

Comment: Your definition of $M$ has a typo: you use $M$ for both the module of all functions, and the submodule you are interested in.

Comment: Also added a note that as long as the domain is $\Bbb{N}$ or at least $\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$, we can take any (including infinite) sets of nonzero coefficients.  The sums will always converge for each value of $x$.

Comment: The definition given for $M_n$ does not depend on $n$. I assume you want $f\in M_n$ to only be the sum of $(d\mid x)$s where $d$ has $n$ prime factors counted with multiplicity.

Comment: @runway44 yes, for two reasons; the homology will be non-constant that way, and secondly probably a whole lot easier to work with because you can consider simpler "forms" with $\Omega(d) = n$.   See my attempt at the bottom for corrections to this.  Either way is still valid though.  Sometimes $M_n =$ all the same space in homology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to mention a few things I've noticed. I'm assuming $0 \notin \mathbb N$. The function $(0|x)$ is a bit more useless than I thought; since $0 | x$ if and only if $x = 0$, $(0|x) = \delta_{0x}$ is a Kronecker delta at $0$, so it's not very expressive. Removing it makes the theory more elegant.

Let $K$ be a ring. The set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(\mathbb Z, K) = \{ f : \mathbb Z \to K \}$ is a ring under pointwise addition and multiplication and the constant function equal to $1$ serves as an identity. The $\mathbb Z$-submodule $\mathrm{DFR}(\mathbb Z,K) = \langle \{ (d | x) \, | \, d \in \mathbb N\} \rangle_K \subseteq \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(\mathbb Z, K)$ is a unital subring (I'm calling it the *divisor function ring* or $\mathrm{DFR}$ for short); the identity of the ring $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(\mathbb Z, K)$ is equal to $(1|x)$, and if $d,d' \in \mathbb N$, we have $(d|x)(d'|x) = ([d,d']|x)$ where $[d,d']$ denotes the least common multiple of $d$ and $d'$ (because $d | x$ and $d' | x$ if and only if $[d,d'] | x$).

The ring $\mathrm{DFR}(\mathbb Z,K)$ is a proper subring of $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(\mathbb Z, K)$ (a very small one even). For suppose $f \in \mathrm{DFR}(\mathbb Z,K)$, so that $f(x) = \sum_{d=1}^n c_d (d | x)$. Let $D = \underset{c_d \neq 0}{\prod_{d=1}^n d}$. For $x \in \mathbb N$ with $\mathrm{gcd}(D,x) = 1$, we have $f(x) = c_1$. Elements of the divisor function ring are "supported" on finitely many divisors (the "support" here would be the set of $d \in \mathbb N$ such that $f(d) \neq c_1$).

By assumption, for all $f \in \mathrm{DFR}(\mathbb Z,K)$, we have $f(0) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} c_n$ (because $d | 0$ For all $d \in \mathbb N$) and $f(-x) = f(x)$, so really $f$ only contains the data of a function $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$. For other rings than $\mathbb Z$ where this construction might work, this "simplification" of restricting $f$ from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb N$ might not make much sense because let's say $K$ is a number ring, the quotient set $K / \{ \text{equivalence up to a unit} \}$ does not have a meaningful structure like $\mathbb N$ does. So I think $\mathbb Z$ is the right domain to use for this problem, not $\mathbb N$. In general, you could work with say a number ring or a UFD.

Using the Möbius inversion formula, we can re-write $f(n) = \sum_{d=1}^n c_d (d|n) = \sum_{d | n} c_d$ as follows:
$$
c_n = \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) f(n/d).
$$
In particular, if $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, then $c_d = 0$ for all $d \in \mathbb N$, so the functions $(d|x)$ are linearly independent, as you claimed.

---

I'm interested so I'll come back to this answer and edit it, but I need to give more thought to the homology part. I think in particular you might want to define

$$
M_n = \left\{ f = \underset{\Omega(d) = n}{\sum_{d \in \mathbb N}} c_d (d|x) \in \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Set}}(\mathbb Z, K) \right\}
$$

with the differential the way it is defined now, i.e. that for $\delta_n : M_n \to M_{n-1}$ and $d = p_1 \cdots p_n$ where $p_1 \le \cdots \le p_n$ are all the primes (counted with multiplicity) in the factorization of $d$, and $\delta((d|x)) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i (d/p_i|x)$.

The thing that makes me curious is that ordering on the primes, it doesn't generalize well to other rings like number rings or UFDs. It's not that I *want* to generalize, it's that things that generalize well usually are more relevant in an algebraic setting.

EDIT: So, I think I can show that the first two homology groups are zero, i.e. this complex is exact at $M_0$ and $M_1$ (with my definition just above).

We have $M_0 = \langle (1|x) \rangle_K$, and $\delta_0((1|x)) = 0$, so $\delta_0 = 0$ (this is what we expect). We also have $M_1 = \langle (p|x) \, | \, p \text{ prime } \rangle_K$, and $\delta_1((p|x)) = -(1|x)$, so $M_1 \to M_0$ is surjective, and we therefore get exactness at $M_0$.

Now we also have $M_2 = \langle (pq|x) \, | \, p,q \text{ prime, } p \le q \rangle_K$. The map $\delta_2 : M_2 \to M_1$ satisfies $\delta_2((pq|x)) = (q|x) - (p|x)$, so in the homology group $H^1(M_{\bullet})$, we have $(p|x) \equiv (q|x)$. Suppose that $f \in M_1$ satisfies $\delta_1(f) = 0$, i.e.
$$
f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n c_i(p_i|x), \qquad \delta_1(f)(x) = -\left(\sum_{i=1}^n c_i \right)(1|x) = 0.
$$
The latter condition is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^n c_i = 0$ (just plug $x=1$ in the equation $\delta_1(f)(x) = 0$). But in the homology group, $(p_i|x) \equiv (p_j|x)$ because $(p_j|x) - (p_i|x) = \delta_2((p_ip_j|x))$ when $p_i \le p_j$, so we have
$$
f(x) \equiv \left( \sum_{i=1}^n c_i \right)(p_1|x) \equiv 0.
$$

Hope that helps,

Comment: The ordering here is just natural - the usual ordering of the integers.  But the chain map works with any fixed ordering, so it would generalize as long as you fix an ordering first - sort of like monomial ordering in Grobner bases.  Reading this post now on my break

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU : Yes. I'll correct that.

Comment: If you have domain $\Bbb{Z}$ then $f(-z) = f(z)$ because $(d\mid z) \iff (d\mid -z)$, so there's not much extra data.   If you want the domain to include zero then you must stipulate that $c_d = 0$ for all but finitely many.  I liked the fact that without zero, you don't have to, so the coefficients can be _anything_ i.e. of infinite cardinality (the nonzero ones) because that generalizes the finite count case.  Also usual arithmetic functionology uses $\Bbb{N}$ or subsets thereof.

Comment: Yes, please use $M_n = \dots$ with $\Omega(d) = n$, since that would seem to make the homology sequence non-constant.

Comment: I really like your proof of linear independence.  I didn't see that way before this answer.

Comment: Oh, I see, what you did with the rings.  So we're working with a _ring_ and not just abelian groups.  Interesting!

Comment: Noticed a problem with my infinite cardinality coefficients.  Apparently $(1 \mid x) = 1$ all the time, so we might need finite number of nonzero anyway.  That's only if we include $M_0$.  So if we delete it from the sequence my preferred way works.

Comment: Any more ideas on this?  See my question edits for some formulas.  Vanishing sum over prime-indexed coefficients appears in $Z_1$.

Comment: You don't want infinitely many non-zero terms. If you look at all the cohomology theories (simplicial, graph, sheaf, etc.) you always stay within the finitely generated area to get cool results. You could do things in the not f.g. area in theory, but if you don't know what you're measuring yet, start finitely generated. It's simpler. I didn't get why $(1|x) = 1$ led you to that though, that's just one term.

Comment: Well to have the coefficients be _any_ arithmetic function, we need infinitely many nonzero coefficients.  Please feel free to answer the question in either direction.  Note however that the infinity allowed is more general.  Well if $(1\mid x) = 1$ and each $f = f_p(p\mid \cdot) \in M_1$ maps to $f_p(1\mid \cdot)$ then you get an infinite sum of $K$-coefficients when we take $f = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{N}} f_n(n\mid \cdot)$ and map it down to $M_0$.

Comment: A related post that might interest you:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4615997/divisor-indicator-functions-d-mid-x-form-a-k-module-basis-for-the-whole-s

Apparently, we can conclude that $\text{DFR}(\Bbb{N}, K) = \textbf{Set}(\Bbb{N}, K)$ i.e. the whole space is spanned by these divisor functions.

Comment: You might be on the right track with the finitely nonzero coefficient direction.  Beacuse it would be a rarity that $\sum_{p \in \Bbb{P}} f_p = 0$ with $K = \Bbb{Z}$, unless of course $f_p = 0$ only finitely often.  (See my post at bottom where that appears).

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU : For any two primes $p,q$, regardless of ordering, we have $(p|x) \equiv (q|x) \pmod{B_1(M_{\bullet})}$ because $\delta_2((pq|x)) = (-1)^{\text{something}}((q|x) - (p|x))$. That's why I can swap $(p_i|x)$ for $(p_1|x)$ in the homology group.

Comment: Hey, I apologize for being an argumentative ass on FB.

Answer (score 1):

I have a proof that this complex we defined is exact using simplicial homology. The set $\mathbb N$ forms an abstract simplicial complex in the following fashion. Faces are integers, and the dimension of the face $d \in \mathbb N$ is given by $\Omega(d)$. A face $d$ is included in a face $e$ if and only if $d$ divides $e$ (it's my chosen definition). The face corresponding to $d = q_1 \cdots q_n$ is actually a quotient of the $(n-1)$-dimensional simplex; the quotient map is given by considering a set $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ of vertices and for $i_1 < \cdots < i_k$, sending the face $(v_{i_1},\cdots,v_{i_k})$ of $\Delta_{n-1}$ to $q_{i_1} \cdots q_{i_k}$, which divides $d$. (The map may not be bijective when some primes $q_i$ are equal.)

By identifying $d$ with $(d|x)$, we see that the set $\{(d|x) \, | \, d \in \mathbb N \}$ also forms an abstract simplicial complex isomorphic to that of $\mathbb N$, the face $d$ in $\mathbb N$ corresponding to the face $(d|x)$. We denote the face corresponding to $(d|x)$ by $\Delta(d)$, and the whole simplicial complex by $\Delta(\mathbb N)$.

Consider an integer $d = q_1 \cdots q_n$ with $\Omega(d) = n$ and $q_1 \le \cdots \le q_n$ all prime numbers. We claim that the function $(d|x)$, as an element of $H_n(M_{\bullet})$, is zero. For this, consider the abstract simplicial complex associated to $(d|x)$. We thus get a map of abstract simplicial complexes $\varphi : \Delta_{n-1} \to \Delta(d)$ given by setting
$$
\forall k,  1 \le k \le n, \quad 1 \le i_1 < \cdots < i_k \le n, \quad (v_{i_1}, \cdots, v_{i_k}) \mapsto (q_{i_1} \cdots q_{i_k}|x).
$$
as described earlier. Since homology is functorial, this gives an induced map of abelian groups $H_n(\varphi) : H_n(\Delta_{n-1}) \to H_n(\Delta(\mathbb N))$. We see also that $(d|x) = \varphi((v_1,\cdots,v_n))$, so $(d|x) = H_n(\varphi)((v_1,\cdots,v_n)) \pmod{B_n(\Delta(\mathbb N))\,}$. But $\Delta_{n-1}$ is contractible as a topological space, so its singular homology (which agrees with its simplicial homology) is zero. Therefore, $(d|x)$ is in the image of the zero map when considered as an element of the homology group, and is therefore zero also.

P.S. : I was computing with $K = \mathbb Z$, but $H_n(M_{\bullet},K) \simeq H_n(M_{\bullet}) \otimes_{\mathbb Z}K = 0$ too, so it doesn't change much.

Hope that helps,

Comment: I noticed while computing that the reason this proof made sense is because all the functions $(d|x)$ are given the same weight by the differential. If you considered something different, like with $d = q_1 \cdots q_n$, the following definition of the differential:
$$
\delta((d|x)) \overset{def}= \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i f(q_i) (d/q_i|x),
$$
in other words, we weigh $(d/q_i|x)$ with $f(q_i)$ for some function $f : \mathbb N \to K$. Then some interesting number-theoretical things could happen.

Comment: Note that any function $f : \mathbb N \to K$ will given you a chain complex if we write $f(q_i)$ instead of $q_i$. The composition $\delta^2$ would satisfy
$$
\delta^2((d|x)) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i f(q_i) \left( \sum_{j < i} (-1)^j f(q_j) (d/(q_iq_j)|x) + \sum_{j > i} (-1)^{j-1} f(q_j) (d/(q_iq_j)|x) \right)
$$ 
$$
= \sum_{i < j} (-1)^{i+j} f(q_i) f(q_j) (d/(q_iq_j)|x) - \sum_{j < i} (-1)^{i+j} f(q_i) f(q_j) (d/(q_iq_j)|x) = 0. 
$$

Comment: We just considered $f(x)=1$ and that gave trivial homology, but if we considered something like $f(x)=x$, or $f(x) = (m|x)$ for a given integer $m$, we could get some cool results.

Comment: I read that the standard complex is _always exact_.  So then what can we do with this resolution complex?